# dropzone.js options maybe not placed in corret place

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, dropzone

I´m using [Dropzone.js](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) but my option are not recognized at all. I tried to place the code different places, but I´m not sure where it should be placed. I read that the Dropzone.options must be out of document.ready or it wont work.

```
<form action="/" method="post" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>

<script>

var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");
// Disabling autoDiscover, otherwise Dropzone will try to attach twice.
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    paramName: 'photo',
    acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png',
    maxFilesize: 1,
    init: function() {
        this.on("uploadprogress", function(file, progress) {
            console.log("File progress", progress);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: did you already solved it or...?

Comment: @lemonid no unfortunately not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this, I hope it helps.

Click [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lemonid/exLf84ga/4/) for the **JSFiddle Demo**.

Other alternative code, click [**here**](https://codepen.io/Lemonid/pen/xxbOQGa).

```
$(function() {

  Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    maxFilesize: 1,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictResponseError: 'Server not Configured',
    acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.jpeg",
    init: function() {
      var self = this;
      // config
      self.options.addRemoveLinks = true;
      self.options.dictRemoveFile = "Delete";
      //New file added
      self.on("addedfile", function(file) {
        console.log('new file added ', file);
      });
      // Send file starts
      self.on("sending", function(file) {
        console.log('upload started', file);
        $('.meter').show();
      });

      // File upload Progress
      self.on("totaluploadprogress", function(progress) {
        console.log("progress ", progress);
        $('.roller').width(progress + '%');
      });

      self.on("queuecomplete", function(progress) {
        $('.meter').delay(999).slideUp(999);
      });

      // On removing file
      self.on("removedfile", function(file) {
        console.log(file);
      });
    }
  };
})
```